# Joomla Auto Logout

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am using joomla 1.5.My login is with standar joomla module , I am having the request to automatically logoff users once thy close their browser, I dont know how Joomla handles the session or if is there any trick I can do to make this.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the "remember me" option turned off? If your users are checking that, they are never logged off unless you force them.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off cookies, I suppose - Check the *Global Configuration*.

Comment: I dont see any option to turn off cookies at global configuration

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking at this.
You can't clear a session when somebody closes the browser as the server doesn't know this has happened and the session data is stored on the server.

You can't disable cookies as then no one would be able to log in.

In global configuration you can set the session lifetime value to something like 15 minutes and if there is no activity in that period of time the user is automatically logged out.